# Facebook iOS Safari authentication

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am working on the facebook authentication concept in my app, for this I have used Facebook SDK. When fb account is available in settings then I am able to fetch the user info but how to do facebook authentication from safari by creating fbsession when no account is available in settings.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

if (appDelegate.session.isOpen)
{
     [FBSession.activeSession  closeAndClearTokenInformation];

   [NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
   }
else
{
  if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated)
   {
        appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
   }
    [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState status,
                                                     NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error..:%@",error);
        }
       else
       {

        [self updateView];
        }
    }];
}
```

}

I have used above code for facebook safari authentication but its not working. Can anybody know what I am doing wrong in above code.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code as:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

if (appDelegate.session.isOpen)
{
     [self updateView];
}
else
{
  if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated)
   {
        appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
   }
    [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState status,
                                                     NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error..:%@",error);
        }
       else
       {

        [self updateView];
       }
    }];
  }
}
```